# Working out a percentage of a value

Tags: math

I'm trying to workout a equity stake in an investment. I want to plug these numbers into a demo application that I'm building in Java script. It's the math part I'm having a problem working out.

I have been giving some numbers to deal with but not sure how they came up with the equity number.

So here is the apps numbers to be used.

- Total value of the company $800,000

  - investors 60%
  - partner 40%
- Yearly gross profit = $1,560,000
- Yearly net profit = $624,000

So they worked out if an investor was to put in $133,333 they would get equity amount of 0.1
and a yearly return of 62,400

Ok so 0.1 x 624,000 = 62,400
How did they get the 0.1 value from putting in $133,333

for example lets say I had a filed where the user inputs an amount of 80,000 what would be the equity value for that given the above numbers.

If I can figure that part out I can add them all to variables in js and display accordingly.

Updated:

There is only one partner they would get 40% the other number of investors could be any amount but they would make up 60% of the rest of the equity.

Thanks

Comment: The number of investors / partners is missing.  The 0.1 assumes 10 and an even split of the profits.  The investors should get 60% of the yearly net profit, divided by the number of investors.  The partner(s) should get 40% of the yearly net profit, divided by the number of partners.

Comment: There is only one partner and as I said they would get 40% the other number of investors could be any amount but they would make up 60% of the rest of the equity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the numbers you have provided the $800,000 must be the value of the investors 60% stake not of the whole company.

The current investors would be looking to sell one sixth of their total stake which is equal to 10% of the company for $133,333.

Comment: Yes the investors would make up the 800,000. The partner would make up 40% of the company not the 800,000. With that how did they come up with the equity value of 0.1 with this equation. Ok so 0.1 x 624,000 = 62,400 How did they get the 0.1 value from putting in $133,333

Comment: @Chapsterj: Since the investors believe that 60% of the company is worth $800,000, they believe that 100% of the company is worth $1,333,333 ($800,000 divided by 60%). $133,333 is 10% of $1,333,333.

Comment: Ok but I guess what I'm not understanding is how they came up with the  equity 0.1 value.

Comment: They give other amounts with equity values related to that value. for another example. $66,667 = equity 0.05. Another example $200,000 = equity 0.15. I'm trying to figure out if I was to allow the user to add in any dollar value how much equity they would get in return for that dollar amount. Example $80,000 = equity ?

Comment: @Chapsterj: If X is a number of dollars and the value of the company is V, then X is X/V of the company. So $133,333 is $133,333/$1,333,333 of the company, which equals .1.